# Oracle - restrict user access to only one connection

Tags: sql, oracle

I have installed Oracle SQL Developer 11g and I have created many connections and I try to create user which will have access on only one specified connection

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [create a profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310) that limits the number of sessions:

```
create profile only_one_connection
   limit sessions_per_user 1;
```

Then you need to [alter the user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4003.htm#i2058207) and assign that profile to the user:

```
alter user only_one 
   profile only_one_connection;
```

This assumes you have already created the user `only_one` and granted the `create session` privilege. You can also assign the profile when [creating the user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8003.htm#i2065278)